# MPI: Sending and Receiving a three-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c, mpi, matrix-multiplication

Is it possible in MPI to send and receive a three-dimensional array?

I found on this link how you can send a two-dimensional array:
https://gist.github.com/kmkurn/39ca673bb37946055b38

How to send for example a tribble pointer variable like float*** matrix?

Comment: yes you can, but that is both convoluted and inefficient. Allocating your multidimensional arrays in consecutive memory, or simply using `float[][][]` instead (from C99 IIRC) is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of using normal arrays.

Comment: Should I also use two offsets or should bei one sufficient?

Comment: Using *ND*-emulation you only ever have one offset, but it's computed according to how many dimensions you have, like `x + y*w + z*h*w`.

Comment: I advise against ND-emulation in order to keep the code readable. `float[][][]` is the simplest option if applicable.